# CollapsingToolbarLayout with wrap_content height overlaps views

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

When I set CollapsingToolbarLayout height to wrap content my views get overlaped, but when setting to exact height in this case 195dp ,it works well ,can someone tell me how can I use wrap _content without overlapping the views ? I want the relative layout to be scrolled under the toolbar.

Thx in advance

[image]   [image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_relative"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_img"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/random_dude"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/profile_img"
                    android:text="@string/laurent_koscielny"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this way:-**

```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_relative"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_img"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/profile_img"
                    android:text="@string/laurent_koscielny"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_img" />


            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: scrolling stucks in the middle of the image

Comment: I uploaded the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176549/discussion-between-nik-and-laurent-koscielny).